# How can I generate a PDF with custom fonts using AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, fontconfig, node-html-pdf

I have an AWS Lambda function that generates PDFs using the `html-pdf` library with custom fonts.

At first, I imported my fonts externally from Google Fonts, but then the PDF's size has enlarged by ten times.

So I tried to import my fonts locally `src('file:///var/task/fonts/...ttf/woff2')` but still no luck.

Lastly, I trie to create `fonts` folder in the main project and then I added all of my fonts, plus the file `fonts.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/var/task/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

and set the following env:

```
FONTCONFIG_PATH = /var/task/fonts
```

but still no luck (I haven't installed fontconfig since I'm not sure how and if I need to).

My Runtime env is Node.js 8.1.0.

Comment: Not an answer just just to let you know, Node.js 8.1.0 is EOL as of Dec 31, 2019 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtime-support-policy.html

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your fonts into an S3 bucket and then download them to the lambda's `/tmp` directory, during its execution. In case your lib creates `.pkl` files, you should first change your root directory to `/tmp` (lambda is not allowed to write in the default root directory).
The following Python code downloads your files from a `/fonts` directory in an S3 bucket to `/tmp/fonts` "local" directory.

```
import os
import boto3

os.chdir('/tmp')
os.mkdir(os.path.join('/tmp/', 'fonts'))
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket("bucket_name")

for file in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="fonts/"):

    filename = file.key
    short_filename = filename.replace('fonts/','')
    if(len(short_filename) > 0):
        s3_client.download_file(
            bucket,
            filename,
            "/tmp/fonts/" + short_filename,
        )
```